# Insert running numbers to a specified limit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For example, I have a user input cell in A1. Let's say the user inputs a value of 10 into A1. How do I write a VBA code that inserts 1,2,3,...,10 from cells A2 to A11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:

```
 Sub numbers()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = [a1]
    For i = 1 To n
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that helped! Would it be possible to make this conditional? Like, n <> " "